# Save montage as image matlab

Tags: matlab, save, montage

I have 225 image with put together with the montage function in matlab. And I can show them with montage. But i cannot save the montage as a complete image, please help me.

```
path = uigetdir;

D=dir(fullfile(path,'*.tif'));

imcell = cell(1,numel(D));
imcropped = cell(1,numel(D));

figure(1);
title('Drag square to crop picture, end with a double click',...
  'FontSize', 15 , 'HandleVisibility' , 'off' ) ;
axis equal
set( gca , 'NextPlot' , 'replacechildren') ;
imcell1 = imread(D(50).name);
[~, rect] = imcrop(imcell1);
close(figure(1));
% 
for i = 1:numel(D)
  imcell{i} = imread(D(i).name);
  imcropped{i} = imcrop(imcell{i}, rect);
end

h=montage(cat(4,imcropped{:}),'Size', [15 15] );
```

The output on montage "h" is just a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! The value 'h' is actually the handles to the image object created by the montage you made in the figure. What you can do is use [getframe](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) to capture the content of the figure (graphics object) and save it as an image. Here is a very simple example, with the code going directly after yours

```
h=montage(cat(4,imcropped{:}),'Size', [15 15] );

MyMontage = getframe(gca) %// Get content of current axes. I did it with sample images.
```

The output is the following:

```
MyMontage = 

       cdata: [384x1024x3 uint8] % Yours will be different
    colormap: []
```

Hence you can save the actual data, stored in cdata, in a new file and you're good to go!

```
imwrite(MyMontage.cdata,'FancyName.tif','tif');
```

Comment: The script using getframe saves the montage in the same size of the GUI. Is there a way to save the montage in it real size?

Answer (score 4):

I would like to point out a better way to do it. While Benoit_11's way is technically correct, it limits the resolution of the image to the size of your screen. When you use `getframe(gca)`, Matlab is effectively taking a screenshot of the current axes contents, at whatever size your figure window is currently in.

A better way to do this is to use the handle, as it references the actual graphical output of `montage()` instead of what it displays as. To save an image from the handle, you need to get the `cdata` from the object it references with `get`:

```
h=montage(cat(4,imcropped{:}),'Size', [15 15] );
MyMontage = get(h, 'CData');
imwrite(MyMontage, 'FancyName.tif', 'tif');
```

This way you get the full resolution of the montage, not just the resolution from displaying it.

For more information on image handles: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/the-image-object-and-its-properties.html